# How to slide with my finger on mobile the same way the pointer does on desktop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, hover, slide

I am working on a StarRating component in React where people can select their rating from 1-5 stars. It works well on desktop where I can hover over the stars and it changes colors responsively.

[gif of working desktop StarRating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKI9D.gif)

I am using onPointerEnter and onPointerLeave to set the Hover state. I would assume this would work for mobile too, however when I slide my finger across the stars it doesn't change the color because everytime it does onPointerLeave it won't activate onPointerEnter unless I lift my finger and put it back down on another star.

Here is my code.

```
const StarRating = () => {    

  const [rating, setRating] = useState(null);
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(null);
 
  
  return (
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        {[...Array(5)].map((star, i)=> {
            const ratingValue = i+1;
         return ( 
        <label key={i}>
             <input 
             type='radio' 
             name='rating' 
             className="invisible" 
             value={ratingValue} 
             onClick={e => setRating(ratingValue)}
              />

              <StarIcon 
                id="star"
                color={ratingValue <= (hover || rating) ? "gold" : "#e5e7eb" } 
                fill={ratingValue <= (hover || rating)  ? "gold" : "#e5e7eb" }
                width={50}
                className='cursor cursor-pointer touch-auto ease-in duration-200'

                onPointerEnter={(e)=>{setHover(ratingValue)}

                onPointerLeave={(e)=>{setHover(null)}}
              />

        </label>
         )
        })}
    
     
    </div>
  );
};

export default StarRating;
```

It seems like **releasePointerCapture** may be what I need, however I can't get it to work with how I have my component set up in react.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you have a look at touch events as well? `onTouchStartCapture` and `onTouchEndCapture`

Comment: Yes, it creates the same issue.